# How to change checkbox and radio labels and values using loops?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, label

How would I go about changing checkbox and radio labels and values using loops if the information is stored in an array of objects?

```
var products = [];//PRODUCT OBJECT ARRAY FOR DROPDOWN DATA
products[0] = { price:[8.85, 11.95,14.95,18.95]}; 
products[1] = { price:[8.85, 11.95,14.95,18.95]}; 
products[2] = { price:[7.95, 9.95,11.95,15.95]}; 
products[3] = { price:[9.95, 12.95,15.95,19.95]}; 
products[4] = { price:[9.95, 15.95,20.95,29.95]};
```

I have other object properties in there (wanted to save space)

I simply need to code a loop to change 4 radio button labels and 3 checkbox values to those prices. base on a dropdown of 4 items

```
var labels = document.getElementsByName("size");
var productsList = document.getElementById("selectProduct");

for(var count = 0; count < 5; count++){
    labels.innerHTML = products[productsList.selectedIndex].price[count] ;
}
alert(labels[0]);'
```

I know it's bad i'm still earning :(...

HTML :

```
<p class="alignR">
    <input type="radio" name="size" id="small" value="small"><label id="one">small</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" id="medium" value="medium"><label id="two">small</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" id="large" value="large"><label id="three">small</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="size" id="party" value="party"><label id="four">small</label><br><br>
</p>

<p class="alignL">Any extras?</p>

<form id="checkBox">
<p class="alignR">
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="4" value="sauce"><label id="five">more hot sauce</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="5" value="dip"><label id="six">more hot sauce</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="6" value="veggies"><label id="seven">more hot sauce</label><br><br>
</p>
```

is what i've tried...

Comment: How do you expect `labels.innerHTML` to work? `labels` is a `NodeList` containing all the elements with the name `size`, not a single element. You need to index it, e.g. `labels[0].innerHTML = ...`

Comment: Maybe it should be `labels[count].innerHTML = ...`. But you have 5 elements in `products`, but only 4 radio buttons, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Your `label` elements need `for="small"`, `for="medium"`, etc. to link the labels with the buttons.

Comment: Thank you sir! the reason for 5 is because the first one gets removed at some point and the order gets changed in my version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign to `labels[count]`. Also, your `for` loop is repeating too many times -- there are only 4 radio buttons, but you're repeating 5 times. It's better to calculate the number of repetitions from the data than hard-code it into the loop (see my `labelCount` variable).

Another problem is that `labels` doesn't contain the `label` elements, it contains the `input` elements, so you're assigning to the wrong elements' `innerHTML`. I've added a class to the labels, and used that instead.

```js
var products = [ //PRODUCT OBJECT ARRAY FOR DROPDOWN DATA
  {
    price: [8.85, 11.95, 14.95, 18.95]
  }, {
    price: [8.85, 11.95, 14.95, 18.95]
  }, {
    price: [7.95, 9.95, 11.95, 15.95]
  }, {
    price: [9.95, 12.95, 15.95, 19.95]
  }, {
    price: [9.95, 15.95, 20.95, 29.95]
  }
];

var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("sizeLabel");
var labelCount = labels.length;
var productsList = document.getElementById("selectProduct");

productsList.addEventListener("change", function() {
  for (var count = 0; count < labelCount; count++) {
    labels[count].innerHTML = products[productsList.selectedIndex].price[count];
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="selectProduct">
  <option>Product 1</option>
  <option>Product 2</option>
  <option>Product 3</option>
  <option>Product 4</option>
  <option>Product 5</option>
</select>
<p class="alignR">
  <input type="radio" name="size" id="small" value="small">
  <label class="sizeLabel" id="one">small</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" id="medium" value="medium">
  <label class="sizeLabel" id="two">small</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" id="large" value="large">
  <label class="sizeLabel" id="three">small</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" id="party" value="party">
  <label class="sizeLabel" id="four">small</label>
  <br>
  <br>
</p>
```